# Trying to figure out the numbers using the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So More clarity on the question

I want the closet and in between numbers

Closet Means

Input Ex: [3, 6, 18, 23, 26, 36, 5, 17]

Output : [4, 7, 16, 19]

In Between Means

Input ex: [4, 6, 19, 21, 34, 35, 0, 2]

Output : [5, 20, 33, 1]

Hope that makes sense to every one

I've got a sample code and it is not returning the right result

This is my code below

```js
const lookAtNumber = [10, 0, 15, 18, 25, 8, 2, 4, 9, 9, 14, 34, 8, 32]
var sureHit = sureHitLookup(lookAtNumber);
sureHit = [...new Set(sureHit)].sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
});

console.log(sureHit);

function sureHitLookup(arr) {
  debugger;
  
  var sureHitTemp = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    var item = parseInt(arr[x]);

    var temp = [];
    if (item == 1) temp.push(2);
    if (item == 36) temp.push(35);
    if (item > 1 && item < 36) {
      temp.push(item + 1);
      temp.push(item - 1);
    }
    temp = removeArrayItemsListedInTargetArray(temp, arr);
    if (temp.length == 1) sureHitTemp.push(temp[0]);
  }

  return sureHitTemp;
}


function removeArrayItemsListedInTargetArray(arrayObject, targetArray) {
  return arrayObject.filter(function(element) {
    return targetArray.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}
```

The output of this code is [7, 11, 13, 16]

But I was expecting the output is [1, 3, 7, 11, 13, 16, 33]

Comment: _"But I was expecting the output is"_ - based on what, exactly? You mentioned something _vaguely_ in the question title, but I think this question could really do with a better explanation of what you actually want to achieve.

Comment: So you want numbers greater or equal to one and less than or equal to -1? acan figure out what exactly your title means...

Comment: @CBroe If you see my question I was mentioned that I was looking the numbers from array - 1) In between numbers 2) + 1 number 3) -1 number 4) remove any duplicates from output with input

Comment: @PerfectRouletteDeal what is the purpose of `temp.push(item + 1);  temp.push(item - 1);` if only `if (temp.length == 1)` modifies `sureHitTemp`?  And why is `33` an expected value, but not `31` given that `32` is part of the input and having  `temp.push(item + 1);  temp.push(item - 1);`?

Comment: @epascarello Yes you're right but some how it is not returning the right output.. please help me

Comment: @t.niese Because in the input array those numbers are already there.. I mean 32 and 34 so I need 33 only

Comment: @PerfectRouletteDeal I don't see `31` and `33` in the input. Only `32` so I would expect that also `31` is part of the expected output?

Comment: I get why `1`, `3`, `7` ,`13` and `33` is expected, because each of them has an item one smaller and one greater, but why `16` if there is no `17`?

Comment: @Konrad Yes you got the point mate.. 17 is not required this moment cause there is no 16 in the input array

Comment: @PerfectRouletteDeal `17 is not required this moment cause there is no 16 in the input array`: but why is `16` an expected output?  There is a `15` in the input but no `17`? I don't get the requirements you have: is it that you want to have all `x` for which a `x+1` **and** `x-1`  exists in `lookAtNumber`? Or do you want to have for each `x` of `lookAtNumber` all `x+1` and `x-1` that are not in  `lookAtNumber`? (For neither of those the shown expected output matches)

Comment: @t.niese because 14 and 15 is there in the array so I was expecting 13 and 16 not 17

Comment: So why not `19` if `18` is in the array?

Comment: @Konrad becoz 17 is not in the list I want the closet one not always +1 and -1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works as expected.

For example this produces 2 array items:

```
   if (item > 1 && item < 36) {
      temp.push(item + 1);
      temp.push(item - 1);
    }
```

With `item === 2` this produces `temp` as [1,3].
Then you filter `temp` and since there's no 3 or 1 in the source array `temp` isn't filtered.
So you add only arrays with length === 1. So `temp` isn't added.
But you expect `1` in the result from this `temp` which is hopeless.
You should fix your logic/description first, the code is ok.
If you want `1` to be includes, remove `length===1` check.
But this will give a completely different result overall:

```js
const lookAtNumber = [10, 0, 15, 18, 25, 8, 2, 4, 9, 9, 14, 34, 8, 32]
var sureHit = sureHitLookup(lookAtNumber);
sureHit = [...new Set(sureHit)].sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
});

console.log(...sureHit);

function sureHitLookup(arr) {
 
  var sureHitTemp = [];
  for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
    var item = parseInt(arr[x]);
    var temp = [];
    if (item == 1) temp.push(2);
    if (item == 36) temp.push(35);
    if (item > 1 && item < 36) {
      temp.push(item + 1);
      temp.push(item - 1);
    }
    sureHitTemp.push(...removeArrayItemsListedInTargetArray(temp, arr));
  }

  return sureHitTemp;
}


function removeArrayItemsListedInTargetArray(arrayObject, targetArray) {
  return arrayObject.filter(function(element) {
    return targetArray.indexOf(element) === -1;
  });
}
```

Comment: Your output is `1 3 5 7 11 13 16 17 19 24 26 31 33 35` the expected output the OP shows in the question is `[1, 3, 7, 11, 13, 16, 33]`. The OP is not clear on what the algorithm should do.

Comment: @t.niese exactly, my answer is for the OP to reformulate the logic properly